# Node Js heap out for memory using excelJS package

Tags: node.js, npm, exceljs

I am using nodejs to create excel files on the server, when calls is greater then 20 heap memory error I got.
I have use following technique as well but all in vain.

> npm install -g increase-memory-limit increase-memory-limit

I have follow below link as well but still no luck. any suggestion ?

> [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory)

```
pageNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11....40]; //example

for (const pageNumbers of p) {
    data = await getData(p,limit,organization_id,token, baseurl, sideFilter, null, client).then(response=>{
        return response;
    });

    await readAndWrite(data);
}


let getData = (page,limit, organization_id,token, baseurl, sideFilter, worksheet, client) =>{

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    axios.post(baseurl+`/v2/get-export`, {
      page:page,
      organization_id:organization_id,
      per_page:limit,
      filter: "",
      sorted:"",
      ...sideFilter
    },{ headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} }).then(function (response) {

      let dataTemp = response.data.data.data.map((t,i)=>{
        var parent = '';
        var child  = '';
        if (t.teams_relation && t.teams_relation.length > 0) {
          //business logic
        }


        return {
          ...t, 
          content     :  t.content ? convert(t.content) : '--',
          parent_team : parent,
          child_team  : child,
          reopened_comments_latest_content : t.reopened_comments_latest?t.reopened_comments_latest.content:'--',
          solved_comments_latest_content : t.solved_comments_latest?t.solved_comments_latest.content:'--',
          closed_comments_latest_content : t.closed_comments_latest?t.closed_comments_latest.content:'--',
          requester_comments_latest_content : t.requester_comments_latest?t.requester_comments_latest.content:'--',
          tags_impolode : t.tags?t.tags.length > 0 ? t.tags.join(", ") : '--':'--',
          organization : t.organization?t.organization.name:'--',
          comments : convert ( t.comments.map(function(c){return c.content;}).join(",") ),
          user_name : t.user ? t.user.name : '',
          user_email : t.user ? t.user.email : '',
          escalated_at : t.escalated_at ? t.escalated_at : '',
          region_Cluster : getDynamicFieldData(t.dynamicFieldsValue, "5f2ff7557a17f166076f2aa2"),
          mawid_Facility_Name : getDynamicFieldData(t.dynamicFieldsValue, "5f3000d1486e94459b6531c2"),
          hospital : getDynamicFieldData(t.dynamicFieldsValue, "609274609d16481196010c6d"),
        }
      });
        resolve(dataTemp);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}


let getDynamicFieldData = (data, id) => {
    let df = data && data.length>0 ? data.find(d => d._id === id ):null;
    if (df)
        return df.value ;
    else
        return '--';
}


let readAndWrite = async (data) => {
  if (fs.existsSync('./export.xlsx')) {
    const newWorkbook = new excel.Workbook();
    await newWorkbook.xlsx.readFile('export.xlsx').then(() => {
      console.log("read");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error ha yeh while reading", err);
    });
    const newworksheet = newWorkbook.getWorksheet('My Sheet');
    // console.log('columns check ', typeof newworksheet.columns);
    newworksheet.columns = columns;
    await newworksheet.addRows(data);
    await newWorkbook.xlsx.writeFile('export.xlsx').then(() => {
      console.log("updated");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error ha yeh while updating", err);
    });
    delete newworksheet;
    delete newWorkbook;

  } else {
    const workbook1 = new excel.Workbook();
    const worksheet1 = workbook1.addWorksheet("My Sheet");
    worksheet1.columns = columns;
    await worksheet1.addRows(data);
    await workbook1.xlsx.writeFile('export.xlsx').then(() => {
      console.log("saved");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error ha yeh while writing", err);
    });

    delete workbook1;
    delete worksheet1;
  }
  
}
```

> Error  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 137 npm ERR!
> wapp-permutas-backend@1.0.0 start: `node -max_old_space_size=20480 server.js` npm ERR! Exit status 137

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: yes i have solved the problem

Comment: may i know how could you solve the problem ?

Comment: @Gagantous 
you have to add row with loop when you get data from server then you have to commit
worksheet.addRow(data).commit(); 
await Promise.all(promises);
await workbook.commit();

Comment: whats the promise in here ?

Comment: it depends as I am using promises to fetch data from the server because i have data more then 100K normally so i used to get data as chunk

Answer (score 0):

What version of NodeJS you are using? I've read in the link you provided that some people solved it by upgrading to the latest version.
Also did you used `--optimize-for-size`? people reported this helped to solve the issue after specifying the `--max-old-space-size`

Comment: nodejs version = v16.13.0

Comment: npm version = 8.1.0

Comment: i have used --max-old-space-size also

Comment: is this can be issue with pm2 ?

Comment: http://sendanywhe.re/SDUQ2G2Y controller

Comment: did you used `--optimize-for-size`?

Comment: no, is this have to use with pm2 ?

Comment: this is a Node.js optimization flag. btw, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963708/node-js-pm2-maximum-memory-limit) maybe this will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue with this code. I tried to use stream instead of buffer. I am code this using **Typescript**, But the problem is
when the data hit > 250K row it will said heap out of memory. So for a large data, instead of using Nodejs, used **Golang**, very powerful and very fast compiling and writing data.

If you using this and still got the heap memory error try running this instead.

`node --max-old-space-size=<enter amount of more memory here> index.js`

for example

(6GB-like) : `node --max-old-space-size=6124 index.js`

or

(12GB-like) : `node --max-old-space-size=12028 index.js`

instead of running like we usually do.

`node index.js`

But setting the max memory is not recommended since, it take more resource for RAM to procced and will slow down the server performance.

Note, I am using node 14.

```
export async function exportToexcel(res: any, jsonSetting: ObjExcelSetting): Promise<any> {

  // Initiate Excel Workbook
  const workBook = new excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({
    // the most important part, dont forget to set this
    stream: res
  });

  // initiate into variable from jsonSetting; column, data, sheetname
  let { column, data, sheetname } = jsonSetting;
  // default name for sheet if null
  let defaultsheetname = sheetname ?? "Sheet"
  // Add the worksheet
  const workSheet = workBook.addWorksheet(defaultsheetname);
  // Set the column
  workSheet.columns = column
  // Looping for adding the data to excel
  console.log("Looping for adding the data to excel")
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const r = i + 1;
    
    // dont forget to commit for **every** loop
    workSheet.addRow(data[i]).commit();
  }
  // commit the workbook
  console.log("Commit the excel workboom")
  await workBook.commit();
}
```

`res: any`
-> refers to response, request method in expressjs or something similar in another framework like nestjs

`jsonSetting: ObjExcelSetting`
-> refers metadata for my function, included, column, sheetname, and jsondata. For more information, read exceljs Documentation, `ObjexcelSetting` is just typescript annotation, if u using Javascript don't use that

`const workBook = new excel ...` -> refers to the initiate module like `const excel = require('exceljs')` or `import * as excel from 'exceljs'`

The data will return in **Blob**, so u guess it how could you parse it.